# Chained Dataframe transformations in Scala with arguments and conditions

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Scala for which I want to add transformations and filters depending on conditions passed as arguments to the function.

For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```scala
val lst_conditions = List("condition1","condition2",..., "conditionN")

for (condition_string <- lst_conditions) {
var new_df = df.transform(FilterOrNot(condition_string))
}
```

But how I'm defining the function next doesn't work:

```scala
def FilterOrNot(c: String) (df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if (c == "condition1") df.filter($"price" >= $"avg_price")
  else if (c == "condition2") df.filter($"price" >= $"median_price")
// If the condition is different do nothing.
}
```

The error I get is:

```scala
<console>:73: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
         else if ...
              ^
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score -1):

I think perhaps a little more info about why the next function doesn't work, or what it's not doing would be useful.

The one thing I would maybe recommend adding is a final default to your custom transformation as follows:

```
def FilterOrNot(c: String) (df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if (c == "condition1") df.filter($"price" >= $"avg_price")
  else if (c == "condition2") df.filter($"price" >= $"median_price")
  else df 
}
```